# How to disable XML DTD validation in Oracle DB?

Tags: xml, database, oracle, validation, dtd

I am using following statement in select portion of the query:

```
extract(XMLTYPE(doc.payload),'/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/DOCUMENTID')
```

it works well if the `doc.payload` contains `XML` without `DTD` declaration, but raises an error when `DTD` declaration is present as Oracle tries to validate the document but cannot find the `DTD`.

How to disable the `XML` validation for this query? I don't want to affect my session setting nor global system setting in this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off validation when you create an XMLTYPE, constructor signature looks like this:

```
XMLType(
   xmlData IN varchar2,
   schema IN varchar2 := NULL,
   validated IN number := 0,
   wellformed IN number := 0)
```

So you can disable validation like this:

```
   extract(XMLTYPE(doc.payload, NULL, 1, 1),
'/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/DOCUMENTID')
```

This will not help you though, if you have an external DTD reference. It'd still try to load it. Is it not possible to upload the DTD file into the XMLDB repository? That would be the simplest solution. If not, there is no 'nice' solution, you have to get rid of the DTD reference before creating the XMLTYPE:

```
   extract(XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(doc.payload, '<!DOCTYPE[^<]*>', '')),
'/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/DOCUMENTID')
```

Comment: References in XML's I use are local, I am currently at home but once I come back to work I will surely check this out :) Thanks!